# Custom grid lines in flotcharts.js

Tags: javascript, plugins

I'm looking for a way how to make a custom grid in flotcharts. I have to use a flotchart plugin for ECG visualization. Here's an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIR6f.gif
Unfortunately grid lines in flotcharts js are not flexible.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by custom grid? Can you explain?